# Moving a UINavigationBar off screen but area underneath is not touchable

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to create a similar "area chooser" as in the "Path" application.
Idea is to have a button in the navigation bar that will trigger the controller to slide away to reveal a data "selector".

Given the following UI structure:

[image: UI View structure]

The main controller is a UINavigationController as I need to add further levels of information later.

Basically it works like this:

App starts with the data table in foreground. User can click on data or on the top left navigation  item.

[image: Data table visible]

Once clicked on the navigation item, it will move the navigation bar, toolbar and tableView aside to reveal the selector table View:

[image: Selector table visible]

The code which moves everything away is:

```
- (IBAction)toggleAreaSelector:(id) sender {
    float offsetX = self.tableView.frame.origin.x == 0 ? 300 : -300;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame, offsetX, 0);
        self.toolBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.toolBar.frame, offsetX, 0);
        self.tableView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tableView.frame, offsetX, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.userInteractionEnabled = offsetX == 300 ? NO : YES;
        self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = offsetX == 300 ? NO : YES;
    }];
}
```

**The problem is:** I cannot click the first item in the selector, "Area 0". I think it's because the `UINavigationBar` still holds a "touch" lock to the area and receives all touches.

Perhaps it's also due to the fact that, when visible in interface builder, I can also see my selector view being *behind* the `UINavigationBar`. After all, that might be the wrong approach to go?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer but [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/newmarcel/MKDSlideViewController) is someone else's implementation of the same navigation idea.

Comment: GOOD link, thank you! Actually this one highlights the key issue imho: It should be separate View Controllers for the left, center and (if needed) right. That way each controller has it's own view and the problem as I encountered just can not happen. Thank you for the enlightenment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy to have found the solution now.

**@jonkroll**`s link was the most helpful, as another people have successfully tried to implement this UI pattern before.

The key issue is about using

```
[self addChildViewController:self.leftViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.leftViewController.view];
```

That way each view controller is managed independently and most important: same for its view.

Once this is done, the managing controller can do almost everything to these views.

Answer (score 0):

why do you moving it out of screen? Why dont just push new view controller with new tableview with you areas?

```
Areas *secondViewController = [[Areas alloc] initWithNibName:@"Areas" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
[secondViewController release];
```

Comment: you could check the link `jonkroll` sent for a demo of the application structure I got in mind: https://github.com/newmarcel/MKDSlideViewController